# mounting NFS share on Android

Tags: java, android, network-programming

i need to mount NFS (Network File System) share from Java application.
When i try to use mount (on a non-rooted device using adb shell) system say that operation is not permited.

Because NFS is in kernel. I prefer to use somy system sollution. 
Does anybody know ho to do it? (Reading and Writing files from Java application).

Or can anybody suggest any light library?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: I suggest that the less your applications have to do with shared file systems of any kind, the happier you will be. Shared files are for users, not applications. The failure rate is too high and the failure modes too numerous.

Comment: @EJP But you do know of a method of doing this, no?